Unable to change border radius and view list at the same time
I need to change the border-radius of an image and view the unordered list when I hover over the image.
I have tried:


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list {
  position: relative;
  top: 2.5rem;
  left: 1.5rem;
  width: max-content;
  display: none;
}

.list-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.list-image {
  float: left;
  shape-outside: circle(25% at 100px 50px);
  margin-right: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.list-image:hover {
  border-radius: 75px;
}

.list-image:hover .list {
  display: block;
}
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/150/150" alt="" class="list-image">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-item">Odio ullam debitis labore consequuntur?</li>
    <li class="list-item">Itaque a voluptas excepturi libero!</li>
    <li class="list-item">Sed nihil dolore ipsa aut!</li>
    <li class="list-item">Maxime nulla nostrum alias maiores.</li>
  </ul>
</div>



I expect the end result like this:

May I know why my code doesn't work?

You need to define CSS class as .list-image:hover + .list instead of .list-image:hover .list


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list {
  position: relative;
  top: 2.5rem;
  left: 1.5rem;
  width: max-content;
  display: none;
}

.list-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.list-image {
  float: left;
  shape-outside: circle(25% at 100px 50px);
  margin-right: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.list-image:hover {
  border-radius: 75px;
}

.list-image:hover + .list {
  display: block;
}
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/150/150" alt="" class="list-image">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-item">Odio ullam debitis labore consequuntur?</li>
    <li class="list-item">Itaque a voluptas excepturi libero!</li>
    <li class="list-item">Sed nihil dolore ipsa aut!</li>
    <li class="list-item">Maxime nulla nostrum alias maiores.</li>
  </ul>
</div>



PS:: Here we have added (+) in between two classes. It is called Adjacent Sibling Selector (+). The adjacent sibling selector is used to select an element that is directly after another specific element.
Sibling elements must have the same parent element, and "adjacent" means "immediately following".
For more information refer to this.

Could you please explain why I need the +? Sorry I'm new to CSS...

@IT_Guy, I have updated the answer and added the explanation related to plus(+) added into the CSS.
